# Alternative switcher.css in Joomla 4

Tags: css, overrides, template-override

Example switcher radio field:

```
<field name="myradio" type="radio" default="0" label="Myradio" class="btn-group btn-group-yesno" layout="joomla.form.field.radio.switcher">
    <option value="0">No</option>
    <option value="1">Yes</option>
</field>
```

The system CSS is loaded from:

```
/media/system/css/fields/switcher.css
```

Where can i put my template based alternative switcher.css which should be loaded ?

I tried all kind of stuff in:

```
media\templates\site\mytemplate\css\
```

and

```
templates\mytemplate\css\vendor\
```

I dont want an layout override of the whole field. Just an alternative switcher.css loading.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using J4.1 style "inheritable" template or its "child" template, the path is:

```
media/templates/site/mytemplate/css/system/fields/switcher.css
```

Or if you are using a legacy template:

```
templates/mytemplate/css/system/fields/switcher.css
```

Comment: Thanks. I had an `<inheritable>1</inheritable>` template, but switched to legacy during work. Things got messy. Solved now.